# I cannot download a complete webpage using pywebcopy

Tags: python

I try to download the complete page of

https://www.skroutz.gr/s/23283554/Asus-Prime-Z490-P-Motherboard-ATX-%CE%BC%CE%B5-Intel-1200-Socket.html

by using

```
from pywebcopy import save_webpage

url = 'https://www.skroutz.gr/s/23283554/Asus-Prime-Z490-P-Motherboard-ATX-%CE%BC%CE%B5-Intel- 
1200-Socket.html'
download_folder = '/path/to/downloads/'    

kwargs = {'bypass_robots': True, 'project_name': 'recognisable-name2'}

save_webpage(url, download_folder, **kwargs)
```

but not the whole page is downloaded

How can I do it? Do I have to combine the above with some other requests?

Comment: `save_page` is not a member of `pywebcopy`, did you mean `save_webpage`

Comment: Even so, I get the same result only some parts are displayed

Comment: Its probably because the rest of the page loads while scrolling.